# Reading PDF417 Codes

Tags: c#, pdf417

I'm trying to create a PDF417 Reader Application. I was able to create PDF417 Codes.

This is the code I use to create the PDF417 Codes:

```
using STROKESCRIBECLSLib;

StrokeScribeClass ss = new StrokeScribeClass();
ss.Alphabet = enumAlphabet.PDF417;
ss.Text = "My Text";
ss.PDF417ErrLevel = 8;
ss.PDF417SymbolAspectRatio = 5;
int w = ss.BitmapW;
int h = ss.BitmapH;
ss.SavePicture(@"D:\pdf417.bmp", enumFormats.BMP, w, h);
if (ss.Error != 0)
    MessageBox.Show(ss.ErrorDescription, "Write Error");
```

When I try to read the file:

```
MessageBox.Show(ss.GetPicture(enumFormats.GIF, w, h).ToString());
```

It gives me:

```
System.__ComObject
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can read the text in this PDF417 Code?

Comment: Obviously `ToString()` does not return the decoded string.  `GetPicture` is returning an object, look at its fields/methods. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems you're trying to read a PDF417 barcode from a bitmap file, generated by the StrokeScribe library. You'll need a barcode recognition library to do that. I recommend Inlite's [ClearImage barcode recognition SDK](http://www.inliteresearch.com/barcode-recognition/) which has a free dev license.

Here's some sample code to use ClearImage with C#:

```
using Inlite.ClearImageNet;
...
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
reader.Pdf417 = true;
Barcode[] barcodes = reader.Read(@"D:\pdf417.bmp");
foreach (Barcode barcode in barcodes)
  {MessageBox.Show ("TEXT = " + barcode.Text);}
```

Disclaimer: I've done some work for Inlite in the past.